# ActiveX launch into a panel (VB)

Tags: vb.net, session, components, activex, panel

I am trying to load an ActiveX Component session into a Panel.

The program launches the Axsession externally, but is there a way to embed that session into a panel.

The Axsession.Launch will launch the ActiveX program externally, there are no properties within the ActiveX component to dock it to a panel within the form.

What happens now is this and it launches the program externally:

```
Axsession.Launch = Sessionlib.launchprogram
```

I want it to load within a Panel instead of opening the program outside the form.

Something like

```
 Panel1.controls.add(Axsession.Launch)
```

Or am I thinking about COM Components/ActiveX all wrong... :(

Thank you

Comment: I don't want to place this as an answer because it would just be my own stab in the dark, but before calling launch, I'd try to set the Parent of the AxSession to the Panel.